# Fails to build node package due to Python

Tags: python, npm, ancs

This seems to be a resolved post just for helping people who is encountering the same issue.

I was trying to install noble(dependency of ancs) and had issue with it

```
$ npm install -g noble
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing xpc-connection@0.1.3

> noble@0.3.13 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/noble
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn /path/to/executable/python2.7 ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at child_process.js:1144:20
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.3-3-ARCH
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/noble
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.3-3-ARCH
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "noble"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! noble@0.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the noble@0.3.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the noble package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls noble
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/yi/npm-debug.log
```

Then tried with changing npm config python version to 3.4.3,

```
$ npm config set python /usr/bin/python
```

Still failed.

But when changed to python2, then it worked.

```
$ npm config set python /usr/bin/python2
```

And current npm configed python version is

```
$ /usr/bin/python2 -V
Python 2.7.9
```

Comment: Your `/usr/bin/python` is 3.4.3? What platform are you on?

Comment: Archlinux
`uname -a`

`Linux qa 3.19.3-3-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 8 14:10:00 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Ah, Arch, the distro that caused the whole PEP 394 problem, that explains it. Anyway, there doesn't seem to be any question here. If you solved your own problem, don't put the solution in the question; write your own answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As abarnet mentioned, this issue caused by archlinux distro, and my own solution is change the npm config python version to /usr/bin/python2.

```
$ npm config set python /usr/bin/python2
```